# How to know the call state in android

Tags: android

i know from Phonestatelistener we will get to know, the call type like its incoming, or ringing or picked etc.. But once call ends i.e once phone reaches idle state, i want to know what was the state of call, was it picked, missed or rejected

lets take, +91123456789 is an incoming call, after call ends, the number will be stored in phone call log as missed call,

is there a way to fetch the recent state from call log for the particular number +91123456789, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that can query the call log for a missed call. Basically, you will have to trigger this and make sure that you give the call log some time ( a few seconds should do it) to write the information otherwise if you check the call log too soon you will not find the most recent call.

```
int MISSED_CALL_TYPE = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
final String[] projection = null;
final String selection = null;
final String[] selectionArgs = null;
final String sortOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
Cursor cursor = null;
try{
   // cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
   //         Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
   //         projection,
   //         selection,
   //         selectionArgs,
   //         sortOrder);
cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "=? ", yourNumber, sortOrder);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
            String callLogID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID));
            String callNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            String callDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
            String callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
            String isCallNew = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW));
            if(Integer.parseInt(callType) == MISSED_CALL_TYPE && Integer.parseInt(isCallNew) > 0){
                if (_debug) Log.v("Missed Call Found: " + callNumber);
break ;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            if (_debug) Log.e("ERROR: " + ex.toString());
        }finally{
            cursor.close();
        }
```

I hope you find this useful, in the same way you can get other states.

Do add this permission in manifest 
    android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Comment: Hi, thank you, i found one way that is phonestatelistener, this work well if its one call. suppose if i have received a call & i get another incoming call, that will be in wait state, i need to know how to catch that waiting call & check is it missed call or not?

Comment: thats what this code do, if you have a missed call then you can query calllogs to check if the recent miss call is from that particular number which was waiting

Comment: But as you told, phone does take sometime to update its log, so sometimes the info is not accurate right?

Comment: use postdelay final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);

Comment: Ok, great, ill check but one last thing i want to know. directly by passing the number, we can find the recent state i.e its missed call, or accepted or rejected?. This iteration is bit time consuming na for phone. so can we get it in oneshot by passing number

Comment: Can one keep the previous call somehow and compare it to the new one ? Can I detect if a call I made was connected (so the user payed the connection cost) ? Zero seconds is not enough I guess

Comment: No, here my query was. By passing number via query through content URI, cant we get the state? i.e missed or rejected or accepted like that. Any help please